# how to add a work item to an existing workflow at an Azure DevOps Server project?

Tags: tfs, azure-boards, azure-devops-server

I just install a new copy of Azure DevOps Server (TFS) to my own computer.
the only work items I can use right now are: **"Epic"**, **"Issue"** & **"Task"**.

**Now my Question is:**

How can I add the work items "User Story", "feature"& "Bug"?

Thanks any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, If the answer resolved your question, you could Accept it as an Answer , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)

Answer (score 1):

Because when you created the team project you chose Basic process template, you need to choose Agile/Scrum/CMMI.

Try to create a new project with Agile/Scrum/CMMI process template.

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/work-items/guidance/choose-process?view=azure-devops&tabs=basic-process) more info.

[image]

Comment: @niryakov You're welcome :) You can [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Shayki Abramczyk.

> How can I add the work items "User Story", "feature"& "Bug"?

We could create work item via **Agile process**, then we could add work items User Story, Feature and Bug.

If you still want to use Basic Process template and your TFS version is Azure DevOps Server 2019 or later versions. You could create collection via Inheritance process model, then open Collection Settings->Process->select Inheritance process->click the button **New work item type** to [add new work item type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/add-custom-wit?view=azure-devops-2020).

[image]

If you are using On-premises XML process model, you could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/reference/on-premises-xml-process-model?view=azure-devops-2020) to add work item type.